# How to sum rows from a CSV only when not all values are above zero and not all below zero?

Tags: python, pandas

For me to analyze when all 5 values are greater than zero, I use it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

print(df.loc[
    (df['pressao1'] > 0) & 
    (df['pressao2'] > 0) & 
    (df['pressao3'] > 0) & 
    (df['pressao4'] > 0) & 
    (df['pressao5'] > 0), 
    'PROFIT/LOSS'
    ].sum())
```

But what if I want to calculate values when not all values are greater than zero and not all values are less than zero? Only when mixed values exist.

Example:

```
1,2,3,4,5 → SKIP
-1,2,3,7,-1 → SUM
-1,-2,-3,-4,-5 → SKIP
```

I tried using `not all and not all` but it was not accepted:

```
print(df.loc[
    not all(value>0 for value in [df['pressao1'],df['pressao2'],df['pressao3'],df['pressao4'],df['pressao5']]) 
    and 
    not all(value<0 for value in [df['pressao1'],df['pressao2'],df['pressao3'],df['pressao4'],df['pressao5']]), 
    'PROFIT/LOSS'
    ].sum())
```

But it gives me the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: can you try replacing `and` with `&`

Comment: Yes @lsr729 , but it generates syntax errors making it impossible to even complete the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (so we only run the filter once):

```
cols = df.filter(regex=r'^pressao[1-5]$')
```

Then use that to index into your DF:

```
wanted = df.loc[~cols.eq(0).any(1) & cols.lt(0).any(1) & cols.gt(0).any(1), 'PROFIT/LOSS'].sum()
```

Comment: Hi friend, first I would like to thank you for your magnificent support. But we ran into a problem, in this filter, values equal to zero enter the filter, in my expected resulto the return would only be if there are values above zero and below zero, but not zero.

Comment: Would you mind helping me readjust this question, please?

Comment: @BrondbyIF to clarify - you only want rows that contain at least one negative and one positive value, right?

Comment: For example: ```-1,0,-2,3,5 → SKIP``` but ```-1,-2,1,3,5 → SUM```, must be mixed values with negative and positive but not containing zero.

Comment: @BrondbyIF Oh sorry - so any 0 in the row is a skip?

Comment: Yeah mate, exactly! But no need to apologize, your answer in that current model has already helped me a lot to work with other future needs as well.

Comment: @BrondbyIF okay... try the update - think that should work for you (and if you don't like the negation... you can do it by `cols.ne(0).all(1)`)